# Proof that restriction of hermitian operator to its invariant subspace is also hermitian

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, operator-algebras

Proof that restriction of hermitian operator to its invariant subspace is also hermitian

What would be the most elegant way to prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L$ be invariant subspace of $A$, then
$$
\begin{align}
A\text{ is Hermitian}&\Longleftrightarrow
\forall x,y\in H\quad \langle Ax,y\rangle=\langle x,Ay\rangle\\
&\Longrightarrow
\forall x,y\in L\quad \langle Ax,y\rangle=\langle x,Ay\rangle\\
&\Longleftrightarrow
A|_L \text{ is Hermitian}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ an Hermitian operator ($A=A^\dagger$) and $P$ a projection onto the subspace $V$. If we define the restriction of $A$ to the subspace $V$ as $A_V=PAP$, then

$$
(PAP)^\dagger=P^\dagger A^\dagger P^\dagger= PAP
$$

Properties used:

1. $(AB)^\dagger=B^\dagger A^\dagger$
2. projections are hermitian operator, since $P=\sum_i |i\rangle \langle i|$ and $(|\psi\rangle\langle \phi |)^\dagger=|\phi\rangle \langle \psi |$, therefore, thanks to the linearity in the second argument of the inner product, we have $P^\dagger=P$